# Contact form html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm reasonably new to this, and i'm unsure as to where I can add my email, so my Submit button, will actually submit..

Here's the code, Should I even be looking here? or should I be in my functions.php?

```
          <h2>contact form</h2>

          <div id="note"></div>
        <div id="fields">
          <form id="ajax-contact-form" action="javascript:alert('success!');">
          <div class="clear"></div>

          <INPUT type="text" name="name" value="Your full name:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your full name:'" 
                    onFocus="if(this.value =='Your full name:' ) this.value=''">
          <div class="clear"></div>

          <INPUT type="text" name="email" value="Your email:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your email:'" 
                    onFocus="if(this.value =='Your email:' ) this.value=''">
          <div class="clear"></div>

          <INPUT type="text" name="phone" value="Phone number:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Phone number:'" 
                    onFocus="if(this.value =='Phone number:' ) this.value=''">
          <div class="clear"></div>

          <TEXTAREA NAME="content" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Message:'" 
                    onFocus="if(this.value =='Message:' ) this.value=''">Message:</TEXTAREA>
          <div class="clear"></div>

          <div class="left">
          <INPUT class="capthca" type="text" name="capthca" value="Capthca:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Capthca:'" 
                    onFocus="if(this.value =='Capthca:' ) this.value=''"> 
          <div class="clear"></div>                                             
          <INPUT class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
          </div>
          <img src="captcha/captcha.php">
          <div class="clear"></div>
          </form>
        </div>



        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    <!--content end -->
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: What is wrong with this as it is?

Comment: Do you want the form to submit directly to your email address?

Comment: Is there any error or undesired behavior? You need to give more details.

Comment: `value="Your full name:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') ` — please don't use the default value as a substitute for a [label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the value of `action="javascript:alert('success!');"` with a URL. You should also use [`method="POST"`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

You then need to configure your webserver to run a program when the URL is requested. That program will read the submitted form data, send the email, and return an HTML document to the server (which will pass it along to the browser).

You can write the program in any programming language you like (subject to what your webserver supports). Options may include Java (via servlets), PHP (via mod_php), Perl (via PSGI/Plack/FastCGI), Python (via PWSGI), JavaScript (via Node), and many others).

---

There is no reliable way to [send the email directly from the browser](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) and JavaScript won't make it easier to do so.